# Create directory in specific folder using Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel-5, storage, create-directory

I am currently working on Laravel and I have created a symbolic link that connects public directory to storage using:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Inside the directory, I have another folder named `user_uploads` where I save the files uploaded by the users. I have an input field that looks like this:

```
<input type="file" name="image[]" id="imgInp" accept="image/jpeg, image/png, image/bmp, image/svg" multiple="multiple">
```

I validate the file and then what I do is:

```
 $image = $request->image;
    if($image){
        foreach($image as $image){
            $image = (array) $image; //convert the object to array
            // Now, I need to create the directory here and save the image(s) there
           // And, I have to name the folder the id of the row (row means the row of the database where the entry is saved). 
        }
    }else{
        return "No image selected";
    }
```

So, how do I do that stuff? And by the way, The folder where I want is:

`myProject/public/storage/user_uploads`.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear, if you have referred a documentation then it is not that difficult to achieve.

According to documentation you can do it like this: [refer here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/filesystem#directories)

> Storage::makeDirectory($directory);

Where `$directory` is a path to the directory you want to create, eg.:

```
Storage::makeDirectory("myProject/public/storage/user_uploads/directory_you_want_to_create");
```

Comment: I tried that before posting the question and it doesn't work!

Comment: please update your question to reflect that also, and add the error you are getting.